# QT Addin can't find Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

So I have been trying yesterday to install QT on my laptop for my studies but after installing it I ran into some problems. I was trying to do the configure and nmake part but I couldn't find those files in my folder (I searched for it) and then I tried to install the Addin for Visual Studio but I always get the error "The installer couldn't find an installation of Visual Studio 200x."
I installed QT v5.6 and tried to install QT Addin v1.2.5.
Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you working with?

Comment: I recommend to use add-in 1.2.3

Comment: I recomend to install Qt addin from NuGet. Because default Qt installer doesn't support MSVS 2015 for now.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 64-bit

Comment: @SaZ can you please show me where to download it, I am trying to google it but I can't find it :/

Comment: MSVS -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Search "Qt". Or https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408